# Jquery to pure javascript and how the intepreter looks up with dom for elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of questions about the inner workings of JavaScript and how the interpreter handles certain queries

The following JQuery will correctly get all the images that contain the word "flowers" in the src

```
$("img[src*='flowers']");
```

Jquery makes this very simple but what the pure javascript version?

We have a very large DOM. I take it if I do `$("*[src*='flowers']")` this will greatly affect performance (wildcard element). I'm interested in what the Javascript interpreter does differently between `$("img[src*='flowers']")` and `$("*[src*='flowers']")`

Comment: You would use `document.getElementsByTagName()`, and then you would loop over each element, using `indexOf()` on the `.src attribute`.

Comment: jQuery's selectors are implemented using roughly 2000 lines of code: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js - I'm not sure people who aren't jQuery maintainers can easily tell you how *exactly* any given query is processed. What you could try is run one "the hard way" and step through it in the debugger to see which DOM methods are used where.

Comment: Also honestly I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. The Javascript interpreter certainly doesn't handle any sort of queries. Do you want people to tell you how to port the jQuery code to pure DOM manipulation? Or do you want people to explain how jQuery processes the query?

Comment: And last, but not least: your DOM isn't very large. Remember that the browser is capable of rendering your entire DOM, which is a **lot** of work, nearly instantaneously. As long as you're not doing the query in a loop or otherwise unnecessarily often, you don't need to worry overmuch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the clearest way to explain the difference is to show you how you'd write both DOM queries in plain JS:

jQuery's `$("img[src*='flowers']")`:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');//gets all img tags
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < images.length;i++)
{
    if (images[i].getAttribute('src').indexOf('flowers') !== -1)
    {//if img src attribute contains flowers:
        result.push(images[i]);
    }
}
```

So as you can see, you're only searching through all `img` elements, and checking their `src` attribute. If the src attribute contains the substring *"flowers"*, the add it to the `result` array.
Whereas `$("[src*='flowers']")` equates to:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');//gets complete DOM
var result = [];
for (var i =0; i <all.length; i++)
{
    if (all[i].hasAttribute('src') && all[i].getAttribute('src').indexOf('flowers') !== -1)
    {//calls 2 methods, for each element in DOM ~= twice the overhead
        result.push(all[i]);
    }
}
```

So the total number of nodes will be *a lot* higher than just the number of img nodes. Add to that the fact that you're calling two methods (`hasAttribute` and `getAttibute`) for all img elements (thanks to short-circuit evaluation, all elements that don't have an src attribute, the `getAttribute` method won't be called) there's just a lot more going on behind the scenes in order for you to get the same result.

*note:*
I'm not saying that this is *exactly* how jQuery translates the DOM queries for you, it's a simplified version, but the basic principle stands. The second version (slower version) just deals with a lot more elements than the first. That's why it's a lot slower, too.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `*[src..]` you will try to find all elements from the page, but when you use `$("img[src..]")` the search is restricted to `img` elements, like this: `imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img")`

Heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQXpy/1/) getting those images using pure javascript.

Edit:

turn console on so you can see the return from `console.log`

Answer (score 1):

The direct JavaScript methods are `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`. The problem with those is that they are not supported in all browsers, jQuery (through SizzleJS) provides a browser compatible way of doing these things. SizzleJS delegates to `document.querySelectorAll` if it is available, and it falls back on other mechanisms when it is not available. So unless you want to write the fall back code yourself, it's probably best to stick with something like [SizzleJS](http://sizzlejs.com/), which provides the selector functionality without the overhead of jQuery.

Comment: Here is a blog post about the relationship between SizzleJS and the document methods: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/07/04/the-new-sizzle/